# time interval in c#

Tags: c#, validation, intervals

I am having start time and end time as two fields in my database of type Datetime, Now i want that  start time and end time selected by user should not fall within the interval of start time and end time that are already present in database. How to do this validation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to know if a datetime specified by a user falls within two ranges in your database? Do you want to do this checking in C# or actually in SQL (assuming your database is SQL)?

Comment: Can you post the code for what you have attempted so far?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, ensure that `yourStartTime < yourEndTime`, if you haven't already.

Then you can run this query on your database:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [table]
WHERE [table].EndTime > yourStartTime
      AND [table].StartTime < yourEndTime
```

If the count is non-zero, you've failed validation.

Comment: Add some brackets around the * :)

Comment: Bah, I knew I couldn't remember my SQL properly :-D  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(startTime);` which will give you the difference between the 2 dates.  Then, selecting the results from the database you can use the DATEDIFF method in order to compare these values.

If I have understood the question correctly.

Comment: You get some nice methods which you can use in order to workout how many Days, Hours, Minutes etc. have passed.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there's a relevance between the duration between two dates, and whether or not the range between them overlaps.